# Testing jsonp request from hybrid mobile app (sencha touch) on localhost

Tags: android, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, localhost, jsonp

I have a rails server running on a local pc with an api to serve some data to the client hybrid mobile app, which is coded with the Sencha Touch framework.

If I test my mobile app on a browser of another pc connected to the same router, the jsonp request to my local server

```
url: 'http://192.168.1.34:3000/api/login'
```

works good, but if I test this app compiled for android with the same request in a mobile device it doesn't work.

Here is the JSONP code:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
            url: 'http://192.168.1.34:3000/api/login',
            callbackKey: 'callback',
            params: {
                "username": username,
                "password": password,
                format: 'json',
            },
            callback: function (response,data){
             ...
            }
```

Comment: What does it mean "does not work"?

1) Does it work in Android browser?

2) Are the requests from the compiled app getting to the rails server?

Comment: 1)How can I test it in Android browser without compile it like a native app? 2)No requests when I try with the compiled app

Comment: Just run `sencha web start` in you Sencha app directory and than open the URL in the Android phone browser

Comment: If I do that,in the Android browser everything runs ok

Comment: Is the app allowed to access the network?

Comment: Yes, "Full network access" permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution, I added some access origin lines to the config.xml: [Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html)